# how to setTimeout delay .each loop

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to show these images with a time delay. Thanks in advance.

```
  $.each(people, function(i, data){

            if(this.dead == true){
                $('#item7').prepend(' <span style="position:relative; top: 7px;"><img src="images/alive.png"/> </span> ');
                }else if(this.dead == false){
                    $('#item7').prepend(' <span style="position:relative; top: 7px;"><img src="images/alive1.png"/> </span> ');
                }

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean ? You should wrap it into a setTimeout() javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a way.  In fact there's lots of ways.

This is the one I'd probably use:

```
$.each(people, function(i, data) {
    var src = this.dead ? 'images/alive.png' : 'images/alive1.png';
    $('<span style="position:relative; top: 7px; display: none;">')
               .append($('<img>', { src: src }))
               .prependTo('#item7')
               .delay(i * 1000)
               .show('fast');
});
```

It ensures that the element is initially invisible (`display: none`) and then uses jQuery animation delays to queue up the `.show()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout to delay it.
What are those == true and == false operations ?
If you want to ensure your dead property to be false or true, compare with ===, otherwise, a if () is enough.

```
$.each(people, function(i, data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#item7').prepend($('<span style="position:relative; top: 7px;">').html($('<img/>', { src : (this.dead ? "images/alive.png" : "images/alive1.png") })));
    }, i * 500);
});
```

Watch an exemple here: http://jsfiddle.net/cLhvf/

Comment: The timeout can be set to anything... It's just an exemple.
Is this what fguru asked for ?

Comment: OK, that's better.  Now please refactor out all of the OP's repetition ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean.

var delay = 500;
(function(elements, index) {
 elements[index];//do whatever you want to it.
 setTimeout(function(){arguments.calle(elements, index + 1);}, delay);
})(people, 0)

$.each(people, function(i, data) {
 var self = this;
 setTimeout(function() {
  // do whatever you want here
 }, delay);
});

I don't think delay works here. I could be wrong though

All code is untested.

Comment: Yeah, you're wrong, $.delay works here as it's chaining the show effect.

Comment: Yeah. I realized that when I saw Alnitak's code. I thought OP wanted a delay on the prepend though.